# Multiple arrays set into single array variable

Tags: javascript

I have made a function in which I have made a single array by combining multiple arrays set. I want that on onclick each set of arrays is printed one by one.

That means on first click 1st array set will print and then on second click 2nd set of array will print depending on the index of array. But in my function, the function is not working.

```js
a = 0;
var txt = {};

function myFunction() {
  var carsglb = ["{"Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"}", "{"Baleno", "Elitei20", "Glanza"}"];
  txt = carsglb[a];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt;
  a++;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get Multiples Ist Method</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You're using double quotes for the strings and then using double quotes *inside* the strings. So, your string literals are now invalid.

Comment: that arent even `multiple arrays`. That are just invalid objects

Comment: As you can see when you run the snippet I made you, the thing you call an array is not valid

Comment: These are strings of objects and not Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` are used to create `objects` not `arrays`.
You can have an array in an array like so: `[ [a, b, c], [d, e, f] ]`.

In your case, if you want to print objects sequentially, it would be better if you merged your two arrays into a single array.

```js
var a = 0;
var txt = "";

function myFunction() {
  var carsglb = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Baleno", "Elitei20", "Glanza"];
  txt = carsglb[a];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt;
  a++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get Multiples Ist Method</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your code to work by changing "{" and "}" to [ and ]

```
var carsglb = [["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"], ["Baleno", "Elitei20", "Glanza"]];
```

To print the arrays on separate lines I would concatenate a `<br>` tag to `txt` variable

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (txt + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues.

- Your array is not valid
- You initialise text to an object but it is later just a string
- You are allowed to have the array inside the function, but the array is a constant and should live outside the function

```js
const carsglb = [
  ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
  ["Baleno", "Elitei20", "Glanza"]
];
let idx = 0;
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when the page loads
  document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() { // when this specific button is clicked
    if (idx < carsglb.length) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += carsglb[idx].join(", ")+"<br/>";
      idx++;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myButton">Get Multiples Ist Method</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```